# FaceBook app continually crashes on startup

Tags: 8.1, facebook

Suddenly, FaceBook on my WP8.1 Lumia 1020 has started crashing every time I try to open it, just after it starts loading content.

It did this once before and I fixed it by removing the app and reinstalling but this seemed to add a load of duplicate contacts where it tried to link my phone and FB contacts and if it does the same again, soon my phone will be a total mess.

Any suggestions? Is it even a known bug? Where do I go to report it?

Comment: Are you using the beta or the stable one?

Comment: Use the in-app feedback.

Comment: Can you check which version of facebook app you are using? Latest stable build from facebook is 8.3.3.0. If you need an update, get it from store. See if it helps.

Comment: My phone is set to auto-download new updates and reports everything is up to date. How can I tell what version I've got?

Comment: @whihathac In-app feedback from an app that crashes every time I load it?!

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder I don't know, I thought I got a new version after upgrading to WP8.1 but I've no idea how I would know the difference.

Comment: You can check you've the latest version, by searching for the app in the store - if you haven't the latest, you'll see an [ update ] button.

Answer (score 1):

If you experiencing issues with an app, in general, you *could* write a review in the store and explain that the app constantly crashes, even after reinstalling, etc. Responsible app developers do monitor the reviews, and do now have the option to reply when it's relevant.